# League table shows reputation from associating an account

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

The new league table viewable in `/user` shows points accumulated from associating an account. For example, the [top user this week on Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week) earned 100 rep points, but not from actually participating in the site. It seems erroneous for the league table to weigh account associations.

Comment: Well it seems this was just fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now exclude these reputation bonuses from the leagues.  We agree a user getting 100 rep from an association shouldn't be recognized/promoted the same way as someone who has earned 10 upvotes, etc.

Comment: I'm still seeing an association bonus apply to a league: User Catharsis's 202 rep points include a 100-point association bonus: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/179/week/cogsci/2012-04-01/

Comment: No, you are not excluding it. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128628/leagues-still-count-association-bonus) and [this new report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244063/got-the-one-of-the-top-posters-e-mail-but-half-was-the-association-bonus-100) that confirms the bug still alive and kicking.

Comment: Or... 20 up votes from questions because question upvotes now only give 5 rep to the user.