# Leagues still count association bonus

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues, association-bonus

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81456/179757), leagues do not count association bonuses, but at least [one league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/179/month/cogsci) shows a user (in this case, [Catharsis](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/376/catharsis?tab=reputation)) whose monthly reputation *does* include an association bonus.

Comment: I wonder if the bug is related to the fact that person associated their account to this site after they had already been participating on the site.