# Got the "one-of-the-top-posters" e-mail but half was the Association Bonus (+100)

Tags: bug, reputation, email, reputation-leagues, association-bonus

I don't think this was the intended response.

I joined and posted only **one** answer and managed to snag the #4 slot for that week. But had it not been for that initial 100 points I would have been only #18.

Comment: Which site was this? 100 points won't get you very far on the larger sites. For example on SO, the top posters score over 2,500 points per week.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yeah, it was a beta site.  Earth Sciences.  It's not even my area, just something I noticed in the hot questions and knew the answer to.

Comment: Just got the same on ELL.

Comment: Agreed, it's a dupe--but I sure never would have guessed the search terms needed to find it!